# simple preg_match regex needed

Tags: preg-match, php-5.3, strtr

I am trying to preg match for tags in my strings that contain `@[anyNumbers:anyNumbers:anyLetters]` 
i am hoping to remove the `@[]` leaving everything inbetween as a string that i can later filter.
What would be the easiest way to accomplish this?

```
$str = 'Have you heard of the @[159208207468539:274:One Day without Shoes] (ODWS) campaign?  ODWS is an annual initiative by @[8416861761:274:TOMS] to bring awareness around the impact a pair of shoes can have on a child's life.';
    function gettag($text){
    //
            //$regex = "\@[([a-z0-9-:]*)\]";
            //$match = preg_match("/^$regex$/", $text);
                    //return $match;
                    return preg_replace('/@\[(\d+:\d+:[a-zA-Z]+)\]/', '${1}', $text);

    }
    gettag($str);
```

returns

> Have you heard of the @[159208207468539:274:One Day without Shoes]
>   (ODWS) campaign?  ODWS is an annual initiative by 8416861761:274:TOMS
>   to bring awareness around the impact a pair of shoes can have on a
>   child's life.

Comment: i was hoping to thank both of you for your time and troubles.  So far the filter is returning the arrays i need, and the removal of the @[] has not failed yet.  I had to mix both of your solutions to get all this to work, so with out both of you i would not have gotten this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using slightly modified version of your pattern, you can do this:

```
function gettag($text) {
    return preg_replace('/@\[([ a-z0-9-:]*)\]/i', '${1}', $text);
}
```

If you'd like it to be even more specific, we can modify the pattern to be stricter:

```
function gettag($text) {
    return preg_replace('/@\[(\d+:\d+:[a-zA-Z ]+)\]/', '${1}', $text);
}
```

[**See it on codepad**](http://codepad.org/zsOSgXwj)

Comment: i added a sample $str where spaces in 3rd delimiter cause it not to replace.

Comment: Ah, I thought anyLetters would be only letters, it's a simple fix. Fixed it now by adding a space in the character class.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$string = "@[123:456:abcZ]";
preg_match('/^@\[(([0-9]+:){2}[a-zA-Z]+)\]$/', $string, $matches);

echo $matches[1];
```

Comment: Warning:  preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /home/content/06/8649306/html/feed.php on line 114

Comment: That's interesting.  It runs without warning on my box.  In the example provided, the second parameter is clearly a string.  Can you please provide the snippet you're running.

Comment: ya i was trying to return the array created with 
  return $matches[1];  and return $matches, but the first returns nothing at all, the later returns error.

Comment: That snippet is just a simple example.  If you're going to use it, you need to verify that the preg_match actually returned a result.  Try something like if ( preg_match('/^@\[(([0-9]+:){2}[a-zA-Z]+)\]$/', $string, $matches) ) { return $matches[1]; } else { return ""; }

Comment: i am going to try to json encode then decode after the return.

Comment: Also to handle the additional whitespace you updated the example to include change the pattern to /^@\[(([0-9]+:){2}[a-zA-Z ]+)\]$/ .  If there are other characters you're anticipating besides alpha and space, you can easily modify it as necessary.

Comment: Warning:  preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at offset 12 in /home/content/06/8649306/html/feed.php on line 191

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13432/discussion-between-keelerm-and-shawn-e-carter)